# How to change display posts order

Tags: mysql

I have my website with a lot of posts. Each post contains `postID` in mysql. For example if I create 3 post (on fresh site) there are 3 `postID`: `1,2,3`. If I delete last one and add another I would have 3 post id, but: `1,2,4`. I am sure you know what I am talking about.

The thing is, that firstly I added about 10000 posts. Let's call them `"X"`. Secondly I added 2000 posts which I will call `"Y"`.

Right now posts order on my website is from **oldest to newest**, so it is:

```
postID
1
2
3
....
9999
10000 (last "X" post)
10001 (first "Y" post)
10002
...
12000 (last "Y" post)
```

and now I want to add another posts, lets call them `"Z"`. Right now order is from oldest to newest, so it would be: `X--Y--Z`. "Z" would be on the main page of my website (newest posts).

What I want to do is to order post in this order: `Y-X-Z`. So `PostID` from `10000` to `12000` would be last displayed.

I think I could just add a `12000` value to every PostID from `1` to `9999` so they would be the newest one. Am I right? Is this the best solution to my needs?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the case function in the order by clause like:

```
order by case when postID > 10000 and postID < 12001 then 1 when postID < 10001 then 2 else 3 end, postID;
```

Comment: When I do this that happens: http://puu.sh/pGGYz/93bc37fcc4.png. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Whatever is doing syntax highlighting for that snippet doesn't understand MySQL specific syntax.